# how to access object under expander when it collapse?

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, expand, layer

hi guys
i have a code like this

```
<RichTextBox />
  <Expander Header="expand">
   <Grid>
    <Rectangle />
   </Grid>
  </Expander>
```

although i already collapse the expander, i still cant access richtextbox, because richtextbox under layer of expander.
how i can access richtextbox when expander is collapse?

Answer (score 1):

If you're laying out objects in the same row and column of a grid, they're going to overlap.  Both of those objects are in row 0 and column 0 of the grid.

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish.  If you don't want the objects to overlap, use a `DockPanel` or `StackPanel` to lay them out, or if you're going to use a grid, put them in different rows, e.g.:

```
<Grid>  
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RichTextBox Grid.Row="0">
    <FlowDocument>
       <Paragraph>
        <Run Text="Now this doesn't overlap."/>
       </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
  </RichTextBox>
  <Expander Header="expand" Grid.Row="1">
  <Grid>
    <Rectangle />
  </Grid>
  </Expander>
</Grid>
```

Comment: is there other way? after i test your code, it will make positioning by row for that two object